# Could the horizon problem be explained by a finite universe instead of inflation?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

Suppose the universe is finite (either closed or open with a non-trivial topology), any point could be within the horizon of another.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on the question?  This question is too brief!